# Grails String to enum?

Tags: grails, groovy

Suppose I have this enum:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    AUSTRALIA_SYDNEY ("Australia/Sydney"),
    AUSTRALIA_ADELAIDE ("Australia/Adelaide"),

    private String name

    private Timezone(String name){
        this.name = name
    }

    public String value() {
        name
    }

    String toString() {
        name
    }
}
```

Is there a way for me to get the enum using its value/name?
Right now, I'm trying to do this, but it doesn't work:

```
MyEnum.valueOf("Australia/Sydney")
```

What I'm getting from the DB is a string (in this case: "Australia/Sydney"), and not the value, and unfortunately, I can't just alter the type it returns because its an old
system and I'm just connecting to this DB that is shared by multiple apps. Anyway around this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Add the following to your enum:

```
static MyEnum valueOfName( String name ) {
    values().find { it.name == name }
}
```

Then, you can call:

```
MyEnum.valueOfName( "Australia/Adelaide" )
```

Comment: Despite all its other dynamic finders, Grails doesn't have this! Adding it to my bag o' tricks ;)

Comment: @CharlesWood It does! See dbrin's answer to this question.

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderSuraphel, but that's actually still not what the question was looking for. Please look closely at the difference between the enum in the question and the enum in dbrin's answer.

Comment: @CharlesWood You're right. I should have looked closely enough!

Answer (score 9):

For completeness to add to previous answers here are additional options which combine the post referenced from Mr. Haki. This answer is taken from Amit Jain's blog post:
http://www.intelligrape.com/blog/groovy-few-ways-to-convert-string-into-enum/

```
enum AccountType {
     CHECKING,
     SAVING
}

assert AccountType.CHECKING == "CHECKING" as AccountType

assert AccountType.CHECKING == AccountType.valueOf("CHECKING")
def className = AccountType.class
assert AccountType.CHECKING == Enum.valueOf(className, "CHECKING")

assert AccountType.CHECKING == AccountType["CHECKING"]
String type = "CHECKING"
assert AccountType.CHECKING == AccountType[type]
```

Answer (score 4):

With reference to blog http://mrhaki.blogspot.ae/2010/12/groovy-goodness-transform-string-into.html there are multiple ways to convert String to Enum.

```
enum Compass {
    NORTH, EAST, SOUTH, WEST
}

// Coersion with as keyword.
def north = 'NORTH' as Compass
assert north == Compass.NORTH

// Coersion by type.
Compass south = 'south'.toUpperCase()
assert south == Compass.SOUTH

def result = ['EA', 'WE'].collect {
    // Coersion of GString to Enum.
    "${it}ST" as Compass
}
assert result[0] == Compass.EAST
assert result[1] == Compass.WEST
```

Comment: Unfortunately, his values are pretty-printed, so it would be more like `'Australia/Sydney'.toUpperCase().replace('/','_')`, which 1) is ungainly inline, and 2) is _[tightly coupled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)#Disadvantages)_. Any code that uses the enum would have to know about the formatting of the values, and would require updating if the formatting changes.

Answer (score -1):

```
assert AccountType.CHECKING == "CHECKING" as AccountType
```